# How to populate table with json data with help of ajax and angularjs?

Tags: python, ajax, json, angularjs, flask

I am developing flask app. I made one table which will populate with JSON data. For Front end I am using Angularjs and for back-end I am using flask. But I am not able to populate the table and getting error like "**UndefinedError: 'task' is undefined.**"

**Directory of flask project**
flask_project/
     rest-server.py
     templates/index.html

**rest-server.py**

```
#!flask/bin/python
import six
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response, url_for, render_template 

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
        'done': False
    }
]
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': [make_public_task(task) for task in tasks]})
```

I am successfully able to get json data using
http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
**Json array is**

```
{
  "tasks": 
  [
    {
      "description": "Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol", 
      "done": false, 
      "title": "Buy groceries", 
      "uri": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/1"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web", 
      "done": false, 
      "title": "Learn Python", 
      "uri": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
         <!--our controller-->
        <div ng-controller="ItemController">
        <button id="get-items-button" ng-click="getItems()">Get Items</button>
        <p>Look at the list of items!</p>
        <!--this table shows the items we get from our service-->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Done</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>URI</th>                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!--repeat this table row for each task in tasks-->
                <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                    <td>{{task.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{task.done}}</td>
                    <td>{{task.title}}</td>
                            <td>{{task.uri}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
         <script>
                  (function () {

            //create our module
            angular.module('app', [])

                //add controller
                .controller('ItemController', function ($scope, $http) {

                    //declare an array of items. this will get populated with our ajax call
                    $scope.tasks = [];

                    //declare an action for our button
                    $scope.getItems = function () {

                        //perform ajax call.
                        $http({
                            url: "/todo/api/v1.0/tasks",
                            method: "GET"
                        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                            //copy the data we get to our items array. we need to use angular.copy so that
                            //angular can track the object and bind it automatically.
                            angular.copy(data.tasks, $scope.tasks);


                        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            //something went wrong
                            alert('Error getting data');
                        });
                    }

                });
           console.log($scope.tasks);
        })();
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Huey Thanks I don't know I am new in these topics, I mentioned the json data.

Comment: @Huey, I got This is JSON array  not object...

Comment: @neelabhsingh JSON Array is also an object. The `O` in JSON is `Object`. It's just array of objects.

Comment: @Huey console.log($scope.tasks); I add in javascript but still getting error in console  "NetworkError: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR - http://localhost:5000/"
localhost:5000"

Answer (score 1):

If you are populating your data to `items[]`,

```
 //declare an array of items. this will get populated with our ajax call
                    $scope.items = [];
```

Then iterate it as ,

```
<tbody>
    <!--repeat this table row for each item in items-->
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks.items">
        <td>{{task.description}}</td>
        <td>{{task.done}}</td>
        <td>{{task.title}}</td>
                <td>{{task.uri}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```